# XML Key value paire C#

Tags: c#, xml, soap

This is my XDocument

```
   <grantitem adnidtype="306" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <attribute key="AccountNumber" value="1111" />
      <attribute key="DateofMeterRead" value="20161226" />
      <attribute key="Arrears" value="11.11" />
      <attribute key="MeterRead" value="11111" />
    </grantitem>
```

I am trying to read this by using

```
var q = from b in doc.Descendants("grantitem")
        select new
               {
                key= (string)b.Element("attribute key") ?? tring.Empty,
                value= (string)b.Element("value") ?? String.Empty
               };
```

But ist return a null value. Can anyone see some missing?

Answer (score 5):

There are a couple of problems here:

- You're trying to fetch elements with a name of `grantitem` in no namespace, whereas your element is *actually* in a namespace of `http://tempuri.org/`
- You're trying to retrieve attributes as if they were elements. You need to retrieve the `attribute` child elements of `grantitem` and then retrieve the key/value attributes of those elements

Here's an example which does what you want:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var doc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
        XNamespace ns = "http://tempuri.org/";
        var query = doc
            .Descendants(ns + "grantitem")
            .Elements(ns + "attribute")
            .Select(x => new { 
                Key = (string) x.Attribute("key") ?? "",
                Value = (string) x.Attribute("value") ?? ""
            });

        foreach (var item in query)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
}
```

You might consider using creating `KeyValuePair<string, string>` values instead of using an anonymous type.

Note that this is geared towards being able to find multiple `grantitem` elements anywhere in the doc. If the reality is that there's always a single `grantitem` element and it's always the root element, I'd probably use `doc.Root.Elements(ns + "attribute")` instead of using `Descendants` first.

Comment: You could go directly to `attribute` instead of `grantitem`.

Comment: @DavidG: Only if the OP didn't have any other elements called `attribute` in the same namespace. If the document is only ever this, I'd probably go for just `doc.Root.Elements(ns + "attribute")`. Given the structure of the original query though, it's possible that this will end up being part of a larger document. I'll add something along those lines to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I like doing this with a dictionary :

```
Dictionary<string,string> dict = from b in doc.Descendants("grantitem").FirstOrDefault().Elements("attribute").GroupBy(x => (string)x.Attribute("key"), y => (string)y.Attribute("value"))
   .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());
```